# Correct definition of The Subset Sum Problem

Tags: definition, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

Reading the book *Knapsack Problems*, 2004 edition, by Hans Kellerer, Ulrich Pferschy and David Pisinger, about the subset sum problem, I found this definition (Chapter 4):

> Given a set **N = {1, ... , n}** of **n** items with positive integer weights
> **W1, ... , Wn** and a capacity **c**, the subset sum problem (SSP) is to find
> a subset of **N** such that the corresponding total weight is maximized
> without exceeding the capacity **c**.

formally found in Section 2.1 as (sorry, no LaTeX support)

[image]

Looking for pseudo-code samples I found this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), where a totally different, albeit informal, definition is stated:

> given a set (or multiset) of integers, is there a non-empty subset
> whose sum is zero?

Although, it also says *There are several equivalent formulations of the problem*, I don't believe this one and the book's can be called equivalent at all.

Am I looking at two different problems here, thinking it's the same? What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, these two definitions are not equal. The definition inside Knapsack Problems describes an optimization problem. In this case it is a NP-Hard problem. The definition on wikipedia describes an existence problem. This is NP-Complete.

One big difference between both definitions is the verification of the correctness.

- The existence problem can easily verified in linear time. Sum the solution and check whether it is 0.
- The verification of the optimization is hard. Is the calculated solution really the best one, or is there a better one?

Comment: so two completely different problems with the same name? great